# MPI application on HPC doesn't communicate between the nodes

Tags: parallel-processing, windows-server-2008, mpi, hpc

I'm trying to do some parallel programming on a HPC running on Windows server 2008. I'm trying to use MPI and particulary [MPI.NET](http://www.osl.iu.edu/research/mpi.net/documentation/index.php) an implentation of the MPI protocol in C#. Right now I'm following the tutorial to understand the library.

I'm trying to run the program pingpong.exe given with the SDK. It works fine on the HPC if the processes are on the same node (so it's the same utility as a threading system) As soon as it is on more than one node, it doesn't work.

What am I missing ?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us your code.

Comment: I think you're missing an understanding of the configuration of your server.  I'm doubtful that looking at your code will enable us to help you.  I think, rather, this is a question you should direct towards your system administrators.

Comment: IronMan84, thanks but the fact is I havn't code anything yet, I've used a executable file given by the university. It's supposed to work correctly but like Mark said it is more a connection problem, even if I'm new in this technology I'm the administrator of the HPC and they are connected through optical fiber and they can ping each other, it is supposed to work, and I have no idea why it's not.

Comment: Well if you are the sys admin what does MS tech support suggest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've been able to understand why, it wasn't working : the firewall was blocking the message between the nodes. [source](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/is/windowshpcmpi/thread/32a7141a-c82b-49c5-a992-d710b9bbbd7f) It's possible to change the firewall so it doesn't block anything inside the cluster.

Hope it helps the next person.

Thanks Mark and IronMan.